# How do I see du in GB instead of MB in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

This works:

```
du -cshm .
```

But this fails:

```
du -cshg .
```

How can I see it in unit of GB?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

GNU `du` has the `--block-size` option:

```
du -csh --block-size=1G .
```

As **sajb** noted, omitting the block size argument will automatically scale the output (and display the unit). Using any block size argument displays the number but omits the unit.

Comment: At (GNU coreutils) 8.25 -h didn't work, while block-size=1G did!

Comment: @FlorianStraub: I'm not sure what you mean about `-h` not working. It is a supported option which causes the output to be in "human readable" (i.e. with unit suffixes and scaled). But it is true that it is ignored when `--block-size` is used. This is noted in my answer.

Comment: my bad: I meant "-g didn't work"

Answer (score 13):

For convenience, here's reference for macOS:

- `-h` "Human-readable" output.  Use unit suffixes: Byte, Kilobyte, Megabyte, Gigabyte, Terabyte and Petabyte.
- `-k` Display block counts in 1024-byte (1-Kbyte) blocks.
- `-m` Display block counts in 1,048,576-byte (1-Mbyte) blocks.
- `-g` Display block counts in 1,073,741,824-byte (1-Gbyte) blocks.

Here is how the various options work given a `1,234,567 KB` file:

```
$ mkfile -n 1234567k file.txt

$ du file.txt
2469136 file.txt

$ du -k file.txt
1234568 file.txt

$ du -m file.txt
1206    file.txt

$ du -g file.txt
2   file.txt

$ du -h file.txt
1.2G    file.txt
```

Also worth noting, you can configure implicit behaviour though the `BLOCKSIZE` environment variable:

> `BLOCKSIZE` If the environment variable `BLOCKSIZE` is set, and the `-k` option is not specified, the block counts will be displayed in units of that size block. If `BLOCKSIZE` is not set, and the `-k` option is not specified, the block counts will be displayed in `512`-byte blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `du -B1073741824` but beware, it gives the result in integer-units only, and won't be meaningful with `-h`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, it also seems to differ between different coreutils versions (or locale?), since on my host I get:

```
$ du -csh .
32G     .
32G     total
$ du --version | head -1
du (GNU coreutils) 7.4
```